# Can I update an application configuration file without restarting the Jetty server?

Tags: solr, jetty

I have Solr running on a Jetty server, and I'd like to be able to update a configuration file and have my application pick up the changes without restarting the entire server. Specifically, I'm looking for something similar to touch web.xml in Tomcat. Is that possible, and if so, how do I do it?

**EDIT:**

Specifically, I want to update application-specific information in an external file, and I want to get the application to load this new data all without stopping and starting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this (assuming you're thinking of general config reloading). You can have a daemon thread polling the file for last changed timestamp, and trigger a reload. Or you can check the timestamp on each configuration value lookup, if it doesn't happen to often. But my preferred way would be to expose a "reload configuration" operation either through JMX or a URL that is accessible only from the "inside".

Comment: jetty has this functionality, its just a matter of having solr leverage that

Comment: Sure, jetty have a file scanner that can reload the application on file changes, but I interpreted the question in a general manner and without restarting the app.

Comment: Turns out a developer put in an xml file that enables reloading via touching, similar to your "reload configuration" option.

Comment: cool, that sounds like the jetty context deployment, touch a context.xml file and it will force a reload of the webapp, glad you got it sorted out

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Solr 4+ and are talking about schema.xml and solrconfig.xml, then you want 'Reload Core', which is in the Web Admin UI under core/collection management. You can also trigger it from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

From Apache solr admin, go to core admin and reload respective core. If you are using solr cloud, then it is too easy. Just reload configuration via zookeeper. These changes will be visible only after complete copy.